# Network Storage Device No Longer Accessible After 11.10 Upgrade

Tags: 11.10, networking

After upgrading to 11.10, I lost access to my Network Storage Device (NSD). I had access earlier in the day before upgrading.

It sees the NSD but bombs out trying to access it.

I get

```
Unable to mount location
Failed to retrieve share list form server.
```

I broke out my old computer, which is still running 11.04 and it has no problem accessing the drive. So it's not the NSD, it's 11.10.

I tried various things such as installing Samba but no luck.

Comment: Can you add some information here, are you using NFS or SMB, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when going to 11.04 and now 11.10... it looks like a name resolution issue where samba can't get you NAS ip...

I don't know know all the details but I got it fixed by simply adding my NAS IP to the hosts file (/etc/hosts).

so, I have an entry there like this:

10.0.0.10     DLINK-NAS

that did it for me.